# How to post Json data with a key in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I have to send json object as a value with a key.
My Code:

```
var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: clientAdd_url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {Contact: $scope.clientinfo}
    }
```

Contact is a key and $scope.clientinfo is a json object. But it's not working.

I checked in Postman, the format is like:

```
{
 Contact: {
"BillingDetails": {
    "CompanyName": "Shangrila Handicraft Shop",
    "Address": "Kamaladi"
},
"ContactDetails": {
    "ContactName": "Shyam Shrestha",
    "ContactEmail": "shyam@gmail.com",
    "ContactPhone": 9808909090
},
"ShippingDetails": {
    "ShippingName": "Shangrila Handicraft Shop",
    "ShippingAddress": "Kamaladi"
},
"Notes": "Test from Postman"
}
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: @Dustin I found you added curly braces before Contact, but using that format gives me error. I have to use exactly the format I gave to get response from server side.

Comment: Why don't you try putting quotes around the Contact key? "Contact"? That would make it valid JSON. It seems I cannot make edits to your question that's less than 6 chars

Comment: The problem was I was told to send the data in exact format so as to get response. So I was having problem on this. But they managed to take data in Json format. Thus, the problem is solved. Thank you so much for your concern.

Answer (score 2):

place all those in to a obj as below...

```
 $scope.datelvl = { "date": $scope.date, "tanklevel": $scope.Tank_level };
```

later call to backend controller for method like below:

```
 $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: apiUrl + 'yourcontrollername/methodname',
         data: datelvl,
         contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         dataType: 'json',
   success: function (data)
   {
  }
```

Comment: There is no problem in sending normal json data. But I have to send Json data as a value with a key.

Comment: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jquery-send-json-object-with-an-ajax-request/

Comment: Thank you for the url. But it would be better if it's related to angular.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.clientinfo` looks like its a `JSON` object.  By what I understand from your question, looks like you want to send $scope.clientinfo as a string.  For that you could convert the `JSON` object to a string using the `JSON.stringify`

```
data: {"Contact": JSON.stringify($scope.clientinfo)}
```

see: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: You may also want to wrap the whole thing in JSON.stringify as such `data: JSON.stringify({Contact: $scope.clientinfo})`

Comment: made a small adjustment @nandu, as the whole object should be serialized

Comment: @nandu Can't we send object instead of string in value??

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It might useful.

```
angular.module('appCtrl1', []).controller('AppCtrl',function($scope,$http){

var tempData = {"Contact": $scope.clientinfo};

$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: serverURL,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        data: tempData,
    }).success(function(data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data);

}).error(function(data, status, headers) {
    console.log(data);
});
}
```

Comment: I used to have unknown method error. The problem is already solved. They made changes in back end and now I can send json object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. I was told to send json data with a key as I have stated the original format though it has been little edited. So I was having a hard time. I have used the normal json post of angular in my projects. But since it was not the json, I could not send data through any process. I think many of you didn't get my question. But anyway I am so much thankful for your concern. This problem is solved. They made changes in their end.